# How to expose nginx ingress to the public url in EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have ingress in my AWS EKS:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: my-service-example
            servicePort: 80
```

Ingress will redirect all trafic on domain `example.com` to `my-service-example`

The problem is, that ingress is without public url, how can I expose this ingress to the public internet?

Answer (score 0):

You need a load balancer controller in your cluster for make a connection to you kubernetes service (nginx, istio, aws load balancer controller).

In this case you don't say what kind of ingress do you have install in your cluster, so i recommend use the official ingress controller of aws for eks, for the installation of this controller please follow this [doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-alb-ingress-aws-waf/), later you need change your ingress object adding these lines in your annotations block:

```
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
```

With that the AWS Load Balancer Controller interact with the AWS API for create a Application Load Balancer in your Public Subnets because in the annotations the scheme is `internet-facing`